# Macro vb Get Value from filter

Tags: vba, excel

**In this case**

Now I already have a button that record  Name,Last name,Blood,Gender,Division ......
Send to "เก็บข้อมูล"Page //mean Save data Page

Auto Filter by ID  and go to "เก็บข้อมูล"Page

I want to show value that filter by ID  Show at Main Page  Cell A14 in Green Square

[image: "เก็บข้อมูล"Page]

[image: Main Page.Page]

**Record Code**

```
Sub Get_Information()
Dim Lrow  As Integer
Lrow = Sheets(5).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Name = Sheets(1).Cells(5, 4).Value
LastName = Sheets(1).Cells(5, 5).Value
Blood = Sheets(1).Cells(6, 4).Value
Position = Sheets(1).Cells(7, 4).Value
Gender = Sheets(1).Cells(8, 4).Value
Division = Sheets(1).Cells(9, 4).Value
ID = Sheets(1).Cells(3, 5).Value
Medicine = Sheets(1).Cells(6, 7).Value
MedicalItem = Sheets(1).Cells(7, 7).Value
Symtom = Sheets(1).Cells(5, 7).Value
ValueMedicine = Sheets(1).Cells(6, 8).Value
ValueMedicalItem = Sheets(1).Cells(7, 8).Value
 Sheets(5).Cells(Lrow, 1).Value = Date
 Sheets(5).Cells(Lrow, 2).Value = Time
 Sheets(5).Cells(Lrow, 3).Value = ID
 Sheets(5).Cells(Lrow, 4).Value = Name
 Sheets(5).Cells(Lrow, 5).Value = LastName
 Sheets(5).Cells(Lrow, 6).Value = Blood
 Sheets(5).Cells(Lrow, 7).Value = Gender
 Sheets(5).Cells(Lrow, 8).Value = Position
 Sheets(5).Cells(Lrow, 9).Value = Division
 Sheets(5).Cells(Lrow, 10).Value = Symtom
 Sheets(5).Cells(Lrow, 11).Value = Medicine
 Sheets(5).Cells(Lrow, 12).Value = ValueMedicine
 Sheets(5).Cells(Lrow, 13).Value = MedicalItem
 Sheets(5).Cells(Lrow, 14).Value = ValueMedicalItem
 MsgBox "Record Successful"
                 
      
  Sheets("เก็บข้อมูล").Range("$C$1:$C$67").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Sheets("Main Page").Range("e3").Value
  
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Main Page" Then
    Worksheets("เก็บข้อมูล").Activate
Else
    Worksheets("Main Page").Activate
End If

                 
End Sub
```

**Code Button Delete**

```
Sub Delete()

[G6,D6,G7,H6,H7,G5].ClearContents

Sheets("Main Page").Range("A14:M333").ClearContents
End Sub
```

[Excel File](http://www.mediafire.com/file/efa1v2d9niuy1yv/Get_Information.xlsm)

Link Excel File  VB password : game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the filtered data after the `.AutoFilter`:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("เก็บข้อมูล").UsedRange.Offset(1).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Page").Range("A14").PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: That work  thank you sir  , How .PastSpecial Process ?

Comment: it's the same if you copy and paste the data manually and Record Macro to see the generated code https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx

Comment: That link help me a lot  , Thank you for your kindness :)